# Парсинг текста с помощью pyparsing

Tags: python, синтаксический-анализ

Здравствуйте,
помогите найти оптимальное и правильное решение, чтобы распознать в строке `text` 4 элемента:  type, name,  teacher, auditory.
Вот моё решение:

```
text = "lab. Subject name Au. Diachin 511"

word = Word(chars)
number = Word(nums)
dot = Suppress(Literal("."))

class_type = (Literal("pr") | Literal("lab") | Literal("c")) + dot
class_name = OneOrMore(word)
teacher = Word(chars, max=2) + dot + word
auditory = Word(nums, max=3)
lesson = class_type.setResultsName("type") + class_name.setResultsName("name") + teacher.setResultsName("teacher") + auditory.setResultsName("auditory") + StringEnd()
print lesson.lessonParseString(text)
```

Проблема в том, что шаблон `class_name` работает жадно и перехватывает слово  у `teacher`. То есть в данном примере `class_name` захватит 3 слова: "Subject", "name", "Au" и `teacher` не проходит, так как его первое слово "Au" было перехвачено.

## Правила такие:

```
<lesson> ::= <class_type>  <class_name> <teacher> <auditory>
1. type  = <class_type> ::= ("pr" | "lab" | "c") <dot>
2. name = <class_name> ::= <word>+
3. teacher = <teacher> ::= 1{<char>}2 <dot> <word>
4. auditory = <auditory> ::= 3{<num>}3

<word> ::= <char>+
<num> ::= '0'|'1'|'2'|...'8'|'9'
<char> ::= <lower> | <upper>
<lower> ::= 'a'|'b'|...'y'|'z'
<upper> ::= 'A'|'B'|...'Y'|'Z'
```

Если словами, то получается так: 
Текст представляет собой запись из расписания ВУЗа, эта запись должна начинаться с типа предмета `type`, за которым слудет имя предмета `name`,  затем преподаватель `teacher` и аудитория, в которой проводится занятие `auditory`. Тип предмета может быть одним из вариантов "pr." | "lab." | "c.", а предмет состоит из одого или более слов. Преподаватель состоит из двух частей: первая часть представлена одной или двумя буквами, за которыми следует точка (сокращённое имя), вторая часть представляет слово (фамилия). Последний элемент в записи - Аудитория, в которой проводится занятие (3-х значное число).
В составленной мною грамматике проблема заключается в том, что парсер собирает все подходящие слова из записи, включая имя автора без точки, и когда парсер проверяет шаблон преподавателя он упирается в точку и выдаёт исключение.

Comment: не ясно почему backtracking здесь не помогает. Такое же поведение (буквы перед точкой съедаются и не отдаются назад, даже если выражение целиком не парсится успешно) наблюдается и у парсера, сгенерированного с помощью grako. Я не нашёл как нежадное поведение включить и использовал negative lookahead, чтобы обойти проблему. [пример кода](https://gist.github.com/zed/c5f707430aa5e7d65c23)

Comment: Регулярное выражение работает даже с жадными операторами: `re.match(r"(?P<type>(?:pr|lab|c)\.)\s*(?P<name>(?:\w+|\s+)+)\s+(?P<teacher>\w{1,2}\.\s*\w+)\s+(?P<auditory>\d{3})", "lab. Subject name Au. Diachin 511").groupdict()`

Comment: Похожий вопрос задавался тут: 
http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/share/view/178079

Автор библиотеки ответил. Я пробовал по такой же схеме сделать, но не сработало.

 jfs, понравилось ваше решение с использованием grako.

Comment: @ptmcg говорит, что pyparsing не делает неявный lookahead, поэтому (на тот момент: 2006) нельзя `class_name = OneOrMore(word)` использовать. Можно как я в [grako решении](https://gist.github.com/zed/c5f707430aa5e7d65c23): запретить `word` заканчиваться на точку -- это работает, но это хак. Другой описанный по ссылке способ это использовать: `class_name = SkipTo(teacher)`. А в чём проблема с regex решением?

Comment: Регексом не удобно пользоваться, потому что будет надо парсить юникод-текст, для которого сокращения `\w` не работают. А во вторых, там надо вставлять между словами `\s*` и читабельность плохая

Comment: 1. `regex` работает с Юникодом (параметры только подправить и/или сделать сам паттерн Юникодом) 2.  пробелы уже учтены в выражении, которое я привёл.

Comment: Был проверен ваш шаблон так:
`rexp = ur"(?P<type>(?:pr|lab|c)\.)\s*(?P<name>(?:\w+|\s+)+)\s+(?P<teacher>\w{1,2}\.\s*\w+)\s+(?P<auditory>\d{3})"`
`re.match(rexp, u"lab. Subject name Au. Șachin 511").groupdict()`
Буква `Ș` не попала под шаблон `\w`

Comment: `ur""` намекает, что это Python 2 код: `flags=re.UNICODE` нужно ещё добавить.

Comment: Да, сработало!
Мне нужно будет проверять запись на несколько шаблонов, пока не совпадёт. Теперь вижу,регекс в таком случае лучше подходит. Можно в отдельном файле прописать все шаблоны, а потом прверять по ним записи. Это обеспечивает модульность и расширяемость. @jfs, спасибо вам большое. Вы мне указали 2 дополнительных варианта для моей задачи.

Answer (score 2):

Нашёл решение:

```
# Basic sequences:
upperchars = u"AĂÂBCDEFGHIÎJKLMNOPQRSȘTȚUVWXYZ"
chars = upperchars.lower() + upperchars
charnums = chars + nums

# Basic patterns:
word = Word(chars)
number = Word(nums)
dot = Suppress(Literal("."))

# Atomic class patterns:
class_type = ( Literal("pr") | Literal("lab") | Literal("c") ) + dot
teacher = Word(chars, max=2) + dot + word.copy().setParseAction(lambda t: t[0].title())
auditory = Combine(Optional(Word(charnums, max=2) + Literal("-")) + Word(nums, max=3))
class_name = OneOrMore(~(teacher) + word) 
lesson = class_type + Group(class_name) + Group(teacher) + auditory + StringEnd()

text = u"lab. Subject name A. Șachin 6-511"

def test(pattern, s):
try:
    r = pattern.parseString(s)
except ParseException, pe:
    print "Parsing failed: %d" % pe.col
    print pe.msg

return r

r = test(lesson, text)
print r.dump()
```

Ключевым моментом было правильное определение грамматики для имени предмета: `class_name = OneOrMore(~(teacher) + word)`
То есть, слова имени предмета не должны соответствовать преподавателю