# Работа с нужной строкой

Tags: c#

Есть файл с разной информацией, например:

```
01:01:23: Server started on 127.0.0.1:28015
01:01:23: Connecting to authentication server #1 ...
01:01:23: Server external IP: 127.0.0.1
01:01:23: Receiving authentication data from server #1 ...
01:01:23: Hardware ID: f42dffb20dd3a91339a8f1d56860c203
01:01:23: You can't run server with RustExtended on this IP with this port.
Please purchase this modification from a developer before to use.
01:01:33: Server started on 127.0.0.1:28015
01:01:33: Connecting to authentication server #1 ...
01:01:34: Server external IP: 127.0.0.1
01:01:34: Receiving authentication data from server #1 ...
```

Как среди всей этой информации получить именно то, что будет вместо `f42dffb20dd3a91339a8f1d56860c203`, для дальнейшей работы с данным значением?

Comment: Часто можно регулярные выражения использовать, чтобы "среди всей этой информации получить" что нужно. К примеру, на [perl](https://ideone.com/NsBSiE) или со словами на [python](https://ideone.com/BOujZ9). Если необходимо, [можно](https://stackoverflow.com/q/493484/4279) [парсер](https://goo.gl/gLUXwk) [создать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/427088/23044)

Answer (score 1):

```
int main() {
    string s;
    while (cin>>s) if (s == "ID:") break;
    cin >> s; cout << "Ваш ID = " << s;
}
```

> Ваш ID = f42dffb20dd3a91339a8f1d56860c203

Дешево и сердито. Это в С++, но в чистых сях тоже есть функции чтения отдельных слов из входного потока.

Comment: Зачем давать ответ на языке, который не указан в тегах вопроса? Такой ответ практически бесполезен.

Comment: Затем, что по моему опыту, пациенты очень часто путают языки, и под С имеют в виду С++. Правда, в данном случае автор пошел еще дальше, и перепутал С с С#.

Answer (score 0):

```
1.c                [----] 22 L:[  1+17  18/ 26] *(266 / 283b) 0034 0x022                                                                                          [*][X]
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


void main(){

char buf[BUFSIZ];
char *id;
char *id_str="Hardware ID: ";

FILE *file=fopen("log","r");
while(!feof(file)){

fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),file);
id=strstr(buf,id_str);
if(id){
id+=strlen(id_str);
printf("Ya podebil: %s",id);
}

}



}
```

Comment: С++? вопрос задан по C#!

Comment: Это ни разу не С++, ответ на С++ чуть ниже. Вопрос был задан по С, код тоже на С.

Comment: # Забыл дописать - извиняюсь. Нужно C#